# Disable RYUK (Testcontainers for Go)

Tags: go, testing, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines, testcontainers

I'm using bitbucket pipelines to run my Go project tests that use Testcontainers.
Pipelines fail with message:

```
Error response from daemon: authorization denied by plugin pipelines: --mounts is not allowed: creating reaper failed: failed to create container
```

So I set `export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true` that I found from Testcontainers Java docs. It doesn't seem to do anything.

Using `go 1.19.2` and `github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go v0.15.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right after this I went to investigate testcontainers-go source code and found that that all I had to do was to define in my `ContainerRequest`

```
SkipReaper:   true,
```

Comment: Yep, it is documented here: https://golang.testcontainers.org/features/garbage_collector/#ryuk

Comment: @KevinWittek how is it documented there? It's the only concrete thing missing: how to actually do it.

Comment: You are right, would you like to contribute it to the docs @ZeljkoTomic?

Comment: @KevinWittek I'll sure take a look at it. Can't promise due to pre-holiday chaos :)